# How can I obtain Azure Application insights operation id and operation name programatically in spring boot java app

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-application-insights

I have been trying TelemetryClient but it does not give me the id or name. Seems that the dot net version maybe [has more functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#operation-context)

I am auditing an entity in my application and want to capture the operation_Id and operation_Name to store against the audit information.

Answer (score 0):

***Here I have a Spring boot maven application which is having connection with azure application insights.***

- Iam having a controller with endpoint `/hello` by this it is getting trigger to my App insight and getting telemetry data.
- By the telemetry data Operation_ID and Operation_name is also created in my app insight.

**Controller class:**

```java
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.OperationTelemetry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        // Start operation telemetry
        OperationTelemetry operationTelemetry = telemetryClient.startOperation("GET /hello");

        try {
            // Your logic here
            return "Hi surya! Welcome to Spring boot app.";
        } finally {
            // Capture Operation ID and Operation Name
            String operationId = operationTelemetry.getId();
            String operationName = operationTelemetry.getName();

            // Store Operation ID and Operation Name for auditing
            // You can save them to a database, log them, or perform any other auditing operation
            System.out.println("Operation ID: " + operationId);
            System.out.println("Operation Name: " + operationName);

            // Stop operation telemetry
            telemetryClient.stopOperation(operationTelemetry);
        }
    }
}
```

***Pom.xml:***

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.18</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.18</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Console:**

```
2024-02-28 16:21:02.286+05:30 INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Application Insights Java Agent 3.4.18 started successfully (PID 10244, JVM running for 5.921 s)
2024-02-28 16:21:02.302+05:30 INFO  c.m.applicationinsights.agent - Java version: 19.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, home: C:\Users\v-chikkams\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.2

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-02-28T16:21:03.922+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Application             : Starting Application using Java 19.0.2 with PID 10244 (C:\Users\v-chikkams\Downloads\77979867\77979867\target\classes started by v-chikkams in C:\Users\v-chikkams\Downloads\77979867\77979867)
2024-02-28T16:21:03.951+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Application             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-02-28T16:21:05.834+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8085 (http)
2024-02-28T16:21:05.883+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-02-28T16:21:05.884+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-02-28T16:21:05.974+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-02-28T16:21:05.976+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1936 ms
2024-02-28T16:21:06.603+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8085 (http) with context path ''
2024-02-28T16:21:06.615+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Application             : Started Application in 3.649 seconds (process running for 10.253)
2024-02-28T16:21:30.003+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-02-28T16:21:30.003+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-02-28T16:21:30.003+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2024-02-28T16:21:06.603+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] Captured Operation ID: 19190eba6d3d5f9b71f0890fc70eaa9a
2024-02-28T16:21:06.698+05:30  INFO 10244 --- [           main] Captured Operation Name: GET
```

**App insight:**
[image]

Comment: telemetryClient.startOperation does not exist in the Java library. I have tried different versions but this seems to be a dot net function.